# dbGetQuery() in Sparklyr

Tags: sql, r, oracle

My question is simple, does dbGetQuery(sc, query) from the package DBI in R handle Oracle symbol of **left outer join** (+). If not how to write in explicit SQL a query like this :

```
SELECT A.col1, A.col2, B.col11, C.col111 
FROM A,B,C 
WHERE A.col3 = B.col33 (+) AND A.col4 = C.col444;
```

Comment: If `sparklyr` interfaces via `DBI`, would it be the SQL-standard of `select A.col1,A.col2,B.col11,C.col111 from A left outer join B on A.col3=B.col33 left outer join C on A.col4=C.col444`? (Assuming the joining indices are in your `where` clause ...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I dont want to make a left outer join on A and C columns, I want it to be only on the col3 of A and the col33 of B

Comment: What have you tried? What did not work, what was the error message you got? If you want a left out join between two tables with absolutely no relationship on a third table, exactly what do you expect to happen? (I don't know how to do a SQL query involving multiple tables without a join between then.)

Comment: Thanks for your time, here is what I tried and I guess it worked : 

`SELECT SELECT A.col1, A.col2, B.col11, C.col111 from A left outer join B on A.col3 = B.col33, C where A.col4 = C.col444 `

Comment: I'm not an oracle user, does it make sense to do `select ... from A join B on A.i=B.j, C where ...`? Is the `C` table implicitly joined on all co-named fields? Or is it a cartesian join (ouch!)?

Comment: here is an example of the output : [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d80ac/13)